# TensorFlow: Do preprocessing operations get frozen in a graph as well?

Tags: graph, tensorflow, deep-learning, preprocessor

I believe after training, the model saved to the checkpoint does not contain any of the preprocessing operation, as upon examination of the checkpoint model, the operations available start from the input of a model (and not the preprocessing operations that precede the model input).

However, when freezing a graph restored from a point file, where the graph has additional preprocessing operations, does the preprocessing operation gets frozen as well? I have included a preprocessing operation for test time in the graph, and intend to freeze the graph together with the checkpoint model, but the result seem to vary a lot for these 2 scenarios:

1. Put raw image through frozen graph with preprocessing operations included in the frozen graph --> very, very poor accuracy as if no preprocessing was done.
2. Preprocess the image first, before putting the preprocessed image through a frozen graph that does not include any preprocessing operation --> result works as expected with very high accuracy.

So my question is does the preprocessing operation gets effectively frozen, or is it advisable to only preprocess images at test time so that we can leave the frozen graph for performing inference only (and not any preprocessing op)? My intention was to include the preprocessing ops within the graph to make it more convenient, but it seems that this approach does not work.

What is the TensorFlow's take on such a workflow? Should preprocessing be done within the graph and frozen, or should it be a separate task outside of the frozen graph?

Here is how I intended to put the preprocessing ops within a graph and freeze them all:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:

    # image = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name = 'Placeholder_only')
    # preprocessed_image = inception_preprocessing.preprocess_for_eval(image, 299, 299)
    # preprocessed_image = tf.expand_dims(preprocessed_image, 0)
    img_array = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,None,3], name='Placeholder_only')
    preprocessed_image = inception_preprocessing.preprocess_for_eval(img_array, 299, 299)
    preprocessed_image = tf.expand_dims(preprocessed_image, 0, name='expand_preprocessed_img')

    with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
        logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(preprocessed_image, num_classes = 5, is_training = False)

    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

    #Setup graph def
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
    output_node_names = "InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions"
    output_graph_name = "./frozen_flowers_model_IR2_with_preprocesssing.pb"

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)

        # count=0
        # for op in graph.get_operations():
        #     print (op.name)
        #     count+=1
        #     if count==50:
        #         assert False

        #Exporting the graph
        print ("Exporting graph...")
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess,
            input_graph_def,
            output_node_names.split(","))

        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: You should be able to store whatever computation you want in the frozen graph (I do store preprocessing operations as part of my trained models). I'm not sure what does the preprocessing involve in your case. If it's just regular ops with constants they should be saved automatically; if it has variables (global or local, trainable or not), you have to make sure that variables are frozen or preserved as needed. But otherwise you shouldn't need anything special.

Comment: In my case, I'm doing some simple image preprocessing for my input images. When I feed in my images, they are in the form of numpy array to fit the placeholder object in the graph, but this gives me the wrong prediction entirely for reasons I'm unsure. If I edit the graph and change the placeholder to just `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,299,299,3]` and do my preprocessing out of the frozen graph before feeding my data, I get the correct prediction. Have you seen something like this before?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't, although I don't usually work with image data. The only reason I can think of is that the preprocessing you are doing inside and outside of TensorFlow are not exactly the same, but I'm not really sure if that's it.

Comment: Preprocessing will get frozen in your graph if it was in your graph in the first place and you passed the non-preprocessed tensor's name to freeze_graph